# Ubuntu live dvd spins down during boot on 2007 macbook

Tags: xubuntu, macbook

I'm trying to install xubuntu 12.10 on a 2007 macbook.
I have burned the .iso file on a cd correctly and it boots on my desktop, however when I try to boot it on the laptop, while it seems to boot, at some point before loading up any ubuntu graphics or kernel messages, the cd spins down and the screen is stuck displaying a blinking cursor.

I tried rebooting the machine several times but it always does the same.

Although the drive should be worn out (it's a five year old laptop and most of apple stuff is not designed to be usable for that long in the end) both the already installed xubuntu and macos can read the disk correctly.

Any suggestions on how I could boot it?

Comment: On a mac for it to boot through the CD, you have to press C while booting.

Comment: (you can also select the cd from the refit menu) nevertheless i did that but still it wouldn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a dozen tries it worked, I guess with a machine that old and/or dammaged I need to consider alternative ways of installing or buy an external drive